How to restart Eclipse and - clean it through programming
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart()

PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart(useCurrentWorkspace)

I have found the restart method, but I hope the restart can clear the cache (- clean). What should I do?
For example, I upgraded the plugins in Dropins through programming and hope to clear the cache when restarting.

Using "dropins" to install plug-ins is supposed to be the last resort. Using the "p2" installer APIs is the proper method.

I know how to use p2, I'm just giving an example. My question is how to clear the cache when restarting
